# What options are available if the need is to periodically update or create markdown files in Gitlab automatically from data in aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a python script that pulls taskdefinition data from AWS. I run it manually.

I would like to be able to put this script in aws lambda to run periodically throughout the day.

Is there an option in Gitlab (ci runners, etc) that will automatically get the data from aws cloudwatch or s3 and create a markdown file in a repo, something like "daily-build-updates.md" so if anyone would like to check the new updates, they wouldn't need to run the script manually. Just check the markdown file.